# Identify Base URL

Tags: php, adobe-brackets, live-preview

I'm trying to open a PHP file in a browser using Brackets code editor, and it's asking for the Base URL. I've tried numerous different combinations of the file structure, but can't work it out.

The file is located at Macintosh HD/Users/My Name/Documents/Exercise Files/Tutorial Name/HTML Files/03_begin.

I'm pretty sure I need to start it with http://localhost: but am confused. Any help much appreciated.

Mac OS X 10.

Comment: Do you realise that the X in the OS name represents 10? You really don't need to say it twice... we get it from the fact your hard drive is called Macintosh HD anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open your webserver configuration to get root directory of your server. as in case if you are using apache then the file is httpd.conf. In which `DocumentRoot` is your server filesystem location.

for ex:
if your server root is **HD/Users/My Name/Documents/Exercise Files/** then the path in your browser is something like `http://localhost:/Tutorial Name/HTML Files/03_begin`